# D Link DWA 131 internet speed drops down on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, hardware, adapter

My D-link DWA 131 speed drops down from time to time. Sometimes reaches bottom. In addition, it never exceeds 30% of my wifi speed. Any help

Comment: Are you using WPA2-AES? What speeds are you getting? What channel is your router set for... auto? If it is auto, try setting it to channels 1/6/11... try all three. This would possibly eliminate local interference.